# React Native change the state on child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am wondering if there is a way to update a state in a parent functional component from a child component using a function, i want to assign the value of `{item}`  in child component to the state in parent component, i think i did that in wrong way

the parent  class components:

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    year: '',
    month: '',
    day: '',
  };
  render() {
       <Dropdown 
                 label= {i18n.locale == 'en' ? 'Year' : 'سنة'} 
                 data={years} 
                 onSelect={() => this.setState(year)}/>
}
```

the child component:

```
const Dropdown = ({ label, data ,onSelect}) => {
     const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    onSelect={() => this.setState(item )} 
   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => onItemPress(item)}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this: `onSelect` will be the bridge between your parent component `this.setState` and your child component. To do that and be flexible, onSelect should have at least one parameter. Judging from what you have, it looks like you only want `Dropdown` to update year:

```js
 render() {
   <Dropdown 
     label= {i18n.locale == 'en' ? 'Year' : 'سنة'} 
     data={years} 
     onSelect={year => this.setState({year})}/>
  }
```

Now in your child component think of onSelect as a function to call when it wants to update the year value in the parent component:

```js
const Dropdown = ({ label, data ,onSelect}) => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.item}
      onPress={() =>{
       onItemPress(item);
       onSelect(item);
      }
    >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Also just out of curiosity, is there reason why the parent component is a class?

Comment: i have another function at on press onPress={() => onItemPress(item) },

Comment: Where exactly do you intend call `onSelect` then?

Comment: this an old code i want rewrite it, so the is no reasons just i was have enough knowledge

Comment: not sure , but i want to assign the value of {item} in state of year

Comment: Okay try `onPress={ ()=>onItemPress(item);onSelect(item)}`

Comment: onPress={ ()=>onItemPress(item) +onSelect(item)}, it work like that thank you